Does pleading true to violation of probation require you to plead guilty?
A defendant in Texas was given probation with the condition of not getting other charges.
They picked up a charge, and they pleaded true to the violation of probation conditions due to that charge.
Said another way: there was a first conviction (resulting in a sentence of probation with conditions, one condition being that they not get charged with another offence). Then they got charged with another offence, thereby allegedly violating a condition of the first probation. This question asks about the impact of admitting to the truth of the violation of conditions (herein lies the legal question).
Does pleading "true" equal pleading guilty to the underlying charge or only to the violation?

Is the probation condition really not being charged with a crime, or actually not committing a crime? I would be surprised if being charged with a crime for which you were later found innocent would be a probation violation, but Texas is a crazy place.

From what I can hear looking at some court Zoom extracts on YouTube, it seems that the usual is really be do not pick up any more charges @ohwilleke.

@ohwilleke For example, Probation Violations in North Carolina, p 19: "A finding of violation is proper either if the defendant has been convicted, or if the probation court makes an independent finding that the alleged criminal act occurred. That finding must, however, be based on evidence presented at the violation hearing (or the defendant’s admission), not on the mere fact that a charge is pending. "

@MichaelHall Yes, there is. Jen added a link to the plea document, titled "Plea of True and Stipulation of Evidence".
